# PHP String Comparision

Tags: php, behat, strcmp

I am using below PHP function in Behat Mink to check the Email column values are in ascending or descending order.But the problem is its always fails.I just want to check if the subject or From of Email column in all rows are in ascending and descending order.Is there are any other way to do this?

```
public function ValidateColumnSorting($Column, $order) {
    $nodes = // Logic goes to retrieve all rows subject or from column value

    if (strcasecmp($order, "asc") == 0) 
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i < $sizeof($nodes); $i++) 
         {
            if (strcasecmp($nodes[$i], $nodes[$i - 1]) >= 0)
            {
                print_r("Row " . $i - 1 . " val is " . $nodes[$i - 1]);
            } 
            else if (strcasecmp($nodes[$i], $nodes[$i - 1]) < 0) 
             {
                throw new Exception($Column . " column ascending sort order failed.".$nodes[$i] . " is less than " . $nodes[$i - 1]);
             }
         }
      } 
      else 
      {
            for ($i = 1; $i < $sizeof($nodes); $i++) 
            {
                print_r($Column . " column row " . $i . " value is " . $nodes[$i]);

                if (strcasecmp($nodes[$i], (string) $nodes[$i - 1]) <= 0) {
                    print_r($Column . " of Email is same");
                } else if (strcasecmp($nodes[$i], $nodes[$i - 1]) > 0) {
                    throw new Exception($Column . " column descending sort order failed." . $nodes[$i] . " is greater than " . $nodes[$i - 1]);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please format your code! The code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for its order, you can directly sort it in ascending or descending order.
Pass subject or email array to sort() function

```
$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
sort($fruits);
```

It will return the sorted array

```
fruits[0] = apple
fruits[1] = banana
fruits[2] = lemon
fruits[3] = orange
```

You don't need to do it manually.
Read more here https://www.php.net/sort

Comment: I am using this code in Behat Mink automation Testing When user click the email header column then only i validate the row data.Original application is written using Java and Subject data will contain the special characters as well.So i don't know sorting in PHP and java are same.That's why i prefer to go with for loop to comparing the row data with previous row data instead of taking the values and putting into array.

Comment: note on "special characters" -> when you access the PHP string as an array it will return the bytes not the characters, your comparison may be failing because you are expecting it to work on an encoding other than ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Without thinking if there is a more Behat appropriate way of validating the order of elements, your code would probably fail due to `$sizeof($nodes)`, try `sizeof($nodes)` instead.

In Behat, the approach I would take would be to create a generic step definition which could be re-used elsewhere...

```
Then I should see the "css_to_some_elements" ordered as:
| apple  |
| banana |
| lemon  |
```